# Javascript : invalid character error

Tags: javascript

In my `.cshtml` page I have JavaScript function it is working fine but showing error like `Invalid Character`. Here is my code snap :

[image]

Please help me. Not getting where is the error.

Comment: I guess you have an invalid non-printable character (or whitespace, thought I don't know if there are any invalid whitespace characters) after the `}`. Delete it.

Comment: Please post your code, not a picture of it.

Answer (score -3):

Please use like this:
.
[Please click here for details documentation on Jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: Not my down vote, but code–only answers aren't that helpful.